# How to use variables in pyspark functions like months_between

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am newbie in pyspark. Facing difficulty using var in pyspark. It is treating that var as column name and throwing exception.

```
var_date_to='2020-06-01' \
months_between(col("date_to"),var_date_to)
```

> Exception Thrown:
> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`2020-06-01`' given input columns: [......

I tried formatting the input string but getting same exception.

```
months_between(col("date_to"),'{0}'.format(var_date_to))
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert it to column type first

```
months_between(col("date_to"),lit(var))
```

And it will work